# Android soft keyboard hides controls

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

I know there are lots of questions about this but none of the answers are working for me.  Here's a screen in question before opening the keyboard.

[image]

Here's the screen after opening the keyboard by tapping on an EditText, and then scrolling as far down as possible.

[image]

Note that besides the final edit control being mostly concealed, all the text and the button after it are inaccessible.

Here's the fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:validator="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
        android:background="@color/background">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/primary"
            android:text="@string/help_header"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/drop"
            android:layout_below="@id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/help_sub_header"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@color/material_drawer_secondary_text"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            />

        <View android:id="@+id/divider1"
            android:layout_below="@id/drop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/light_gray_background"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"/>

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linear1"
            android:layout_below="@id/divider1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

            <!-- Several EditTexts and such -->

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

It was originally in a LinearLayout and I changed it to a RelativeLayout based on a suggestion, but that didn't change anything.  I have also played with the layout height (wrap_content / match_parent) of the top two levels of view groups to no effect.  Here is the activity declaration in the manifest:

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/application_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

I've also tried adjustPan and it doesn't seem to change. I'm not too concerned about what exactly the UI elements do when the keyboard opens, I just want the whole layout to be accessible by scrolling.

Basically everyone points to the soft input mode, but that doesn't seem to be doing anything.  Is there something about fragments that I'm missing?  Or maybe this is harder than I'm expecting and I need to make a custom layout class and measure the layout and nasty stuff like that?  I can add the activity layout though there's not much to it, or code such as the fragment creation/transaction stuff.

Answer (score 0):

THat's what the keyboard does.  It covers the bottom of the screen.  If you want it to not cover your app at all, you can use adjustResize.  That will scale your app to only draw in the top half.  But if your content is too big it still won't fit and it will look as if your app is covered (even though it isn't.  Scrolling it via a scroll view should work then (although I've never actually tried it).  But the only thing you can do to control the behavior when the keyboard is up is the softInputMode.

If you have lots of adjustable space or whitespace, there are techniques that will shrink you somewhat and may allow your full app to appear in the reduced space.  This isn't the case here, you have too much stuff on screen (except for maybe on a tablet in portrait mode).  So they aren't going to apply here.

Comment: Yeah the scrolling "should work" but it doesn't.  I cannot scroll the content up to get to the bottom of the layout.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was with a library, material-drawer (nice library).  For anyone else encountering this:

https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/blob/master/README.md#i-have-problems-with-the-softkeyboard-how-can-i-fix-this

Call `Drawer.keyboardSupportEnabled(this,true)` and the layout will arrange and scroll appropriately.